# Using "Like" And "As If" In Unreal Conditions?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 1- Why do you talk about him ***as if he were*** an old man? (He is
>   not an old man.)
>
> 2- They treat me ***as if I were*** their own son. (I'm not their son)

Can I use "like" in these sentences above instead of "as if" ? As:

> 1'- Why do you talk about him ***like he is*** an old man ?
>
> 2'- They treat me ***like I am*** their own son.

---

> 3- I feel ***like I have run*** a marathon . (I am just too tired
>   because I just run one kilometre. So I haven't run a marathon.)
>
> 4- You look ***like you have seen*** a ghost. (She is just so
>   terrified. She didn't see a ghost.)

Can I use "as if" in these sentences, 3 and 4, instead of "like". If I can, should I use subjunctive mood or not?

> 3a- I feel ***as if I have run*** a marathon.
>
> 3b- I feel ***as if I had run*** a marathon.

---

> 4a- You look ***as if you have seen*** a ghost.
>
> 4b- You look ***as if you had seen*** a ghost.

Answer (score 2):

All of these forms will be often heard (and read) and may be created by fluent and native speakers. None of them can now really be called incorrect. Strictly speaking "like" is a simple comparison usually followed by a noun or pronoun. "As" or "as if" is a conjunction and is normally followed by a subject and a verb  although often one is elided. This distinction is observed less and less often, and may well be obsolete in the future.

By that rule 1 & 2 correctly use "as if" and 1' and 2' are in violation, but few if any English speakers would object to 1' or 2'. And by that rule 3 and 4 should use "as" or "as if", not 'like, but here I think "like" flows better. I would favor the forms 3b and 4b over 3a and 4a, because the running or seeing is in the past, even if an unreal past, and a recent one.

In general, "I feel as if i had X" pretty much implies that I have **not** done X. Thus "I feel as if I had run a marathon -- because I have." has a humorous effect, because this implication is first believed and then overturned. A ["garden path" sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence).

But none of these are likely to cause raise eyebrows, or confusion, on the part of any fluent speaker.

Comment: So using 4a is okay even though he didn't run a marathon? He is just exaggerating.

Comment: @Talha Özden I think you mean 3a, 4a is about a ghost. But yes, "I feel as if i had X" pretty much implies that I have **not** done X. "I feel as if I had run a marathon -- because i have." has a humorous effect, because this implication is first believed and then overturned. A "garden path" sentence.

Comment: Thank you. But as far as I now and according to this website(https://www.grammaring.com/as-if-as-though): We use "the past perfect subjunctive" after "as if" to refer to an unreal past situation. If the situation is probably true, we use a real tense to express past time: 

He seems as if he hadn't slept for days. (it seems that he hasn't slept for days, but he (probably) has or we don't know whether he has or not)
He seems as if he hasn't slept for days. (Probably, he hasn't slept for days)

Answer (score 0):

3a and 4a seem more felicitous, because their contractions (I've and you've) sound more natural. "Like he is" and "Like I am" are both natural.